# How do I set an event listener on the parent component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, addeventlistener

I'm trying to create a custom context menu that activates when the user right-clicks on a certain part of my page (I'd like the browser's default context menu on the rest of the page).

From the parent element I'm calling the child element:

```
<ContextMenu clickDomain={this.parentRef}>
```

(and of course in the constructor I've created the ref: `this.parentRef = React.createRef();`).

In the child `<ContextMenu>` component I try to set the domain for the `contextmenu` event using the passed ref:

```
componentDidMount() {
        const self = this;
        console.log(this.props);
        console.log(!!self.props.clickDomain);
        console.log(!!self.props.clickDomain.current);
        const domain = self.props.clickDomain && self.props.clickDomain.current 
            ? self.props.clickDomain.current : document;
        console.log(domain);
        domain.addEventListener('contextmenu', 
             this.openContextMenu(self));
    }
```

(Among other things, `openContextMenu` sets state `visible: true` and the x and y coords.)

But the `!!self.props.clickDomain.current` is false (`self.props.clickDomain.current` is null) and `domain` is `document`.

So somehow the child component "did mount" already even though the parent ref isn't in the DOM?

How can I pass to the child component a live reference to the parent component, so that I can set an event listener on the parent from within the child?

Comment: Hey, if you're going to vote me down, please explain the reason in a comment at very least!

Comment: Is there a reason you are tied to use `domain.addEventListener('contextmenu')`? It looks like you can simply monitor `onClick` on the parent component, set a state, say `isContext` state to `true`, and pass that down to `<ContextMenu isOpen={this.state.isOpen} />`. And within `ContextMenu.render`, if `this.props.isOpen === true`, then you can simply `render` your elements.

Comment: @SungM.Kim, thanks for the upvote, and the reply! What you propose would certainly be more straight-forward, but it just seems to me that the visibility of a component is part of that component's state, not really the parent's state. I'm trying to make my context menu component self-contained, so I can reuse it easily without a lot of changes to the host/parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) might be a solution. You could use a state to store the ref once it is set, and pass `this.state.ref` to the `<ContextMenu/>` component.

But I suggest you try this instead:

```
class WithContextMenu extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {open: false};
    }

    openContextMenu(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({open: true});
    }

    render() {
        return (<React.Fragment>
            {React.cloneElement(
                React.Children.only(this.props.children),
                { onContextMenu: this.openContextMenu.bind(this) }
            )}
            { this.state.open && <div>context menu</div> }
        </React.Fragment>)
    }
}

// In any other component
const MyComponent = () => (
    <WithContextMenu>
      <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <p>Right-click to open context menu</p>
      </div>
    </WithContextMenu>
);
```

You could then decorate any component with a contextual menu. Here is how it works:

1. Wrap any component within a `WithContextMenu` component
2. An `onContextMenu` event handler is attached to the wrapped component
3. When the event handler is triggered, the context menu itself is rendered alongside the wrapped component

Comment: Hi Pierre, thanks so much for your reply! I'm trying to understand what your suggested code is doing and how it addresses my problem. It looks like you're setting the event handler on the child of the `ContextMenu` instead of (what I wanted) on the parent? Am I misreading?

Comment: You're welcome! What I suggested was an implementation of the decorator pattern. I updated the example code so that it is more explicit.